# fixed width box with scrollbar height of the full window

Tags: css, scroll

I'm trying to make a fixed width, fixed height box that "mimics" overflow:scroll, but the scroll bar is actually the widow scrollbar (or a pseudo-window scrollbar). What I mean by that is, the box is sitting there and you have the scroll bar on the side of the browser scroll the box contents up and down. Possible with just css? If not, is there a solution with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Your box height is exceeding your window height. In following manner this could happen if you are in resolution 1024 by 768px

```
div style="width:400px; height:1000px; overflow:scroll;"
```

Solutions-

- **css**- reduce height of the box

or

- **js**- control height of the box [screen.Height] for different
  resolutions